# ajax form submission not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Firstly, all my works on php,mysql and js were on local server.For the first time i am putting my work online.But i have encountered some problems doing so.

problem is whenever i submit the form no comment is added to my post .The alert methods `alert(response)` i appended inside alerts "[object object]". Does it mean it is a valid JSON?

**the second alert which is `alert(obj)` doesn't even trigger**

i also get the follwoing error in return :

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of
>   the JSON data
>
> ...tion(b){if(a.JSON&&a.JSON.parse)return a.JSON.parse(b+"");var
>   c,d=null,e=m.trim(...

section responsible for ajax submission is :

```
 $.ajax('../includes/verifyanswer.php',{
        data:{

            'answer_body': CKEDITOR.instances.content.getData(),
            'userpost_post_id': <?php echo $postid;?>,
            'users_user_id': <?php echo $userdata->user_id; ?>
             },
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(response){




           alert(response);
             var obj=$.parseJSON(response);
           alert(obj);
              $('#mainanswer').hide();
              $('#answerform').hide();
              $('#answerthisquestion').show();
              var str="<div class='styleanswer' >"+obj[0]['answer_body']+"</div><div class='customcmntholder'></div><span id='customcomment' class='cmnt' onclick='letmecomment(event);'>Add a Comment...</span><form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'  name='cmntform'> <textarea  data-id="+obj[0]['answer_id']+" class='customcmntform' placeholder=' add a comment......' ></textarea></form><hr>";

              $('#answerwrapper').append(str);
                $('#answerwrapper pre code').each(function(i, block) {
                   hljs.highlightBlock(block);
              });

        },
        error:function(response){
              alert(response);
           }
    })
```

verifyanswer.php :

```
  require_once '../core/init.php';
   $answer=$_POST['answer_body'];

   $post_id=$_POST['userpost_post_id'];
   $answerer=$_POST['users_user_id'];
   if(isset($answer,$post_id,$answerer)){
     if(!empty($answer) && !empty($post_id) && !empty($answerer)){
           $db=DB::getInstance();
           $result=$db->post_and_fetch("CALL login.post_and_fetch_ans(?,?,?)",array($answer,$post_id,$answerer))->result();
                echo json_encode($result);

       }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you said `dataType:'json',`, jQuery will parse the JSON in the HTTP response and turn it into a JavaScript data structure **before** passing it to the `success` function.

This means that when you say `var obj=$.parseJSON(response);` you implicitly convert it back to a string (but not to a string of JSON, to `"[object Object]"`) and then try to parse *that* as JSON, which it isn't, so it fails.

Comment: what does dataType:'json' means? in my verifyanswer i used json_encode ?without it i get an error?i am confused...does json_encode function converts it into json or response will be json as i enforced dataType is json

Comment: @AL-zami — `dataType:'json'` causes jQuery to set the Accept header to explicitly request JSON (which most servers will ignore) and to ignore the content-type of the response and try to parse it as JSON regardless.

Comment: `json_encode` is a PHP function that takes a PHP data structure and converts it to a string containing JSON encoded data.

Comment: what is an accept header ?can you tell me in brief? i have encounter different types of header.it confuses me...why i need to explicitly say to accept json?

Comment: @AL-zami — It is a header that tells the server what kind of data you want. You don't need to send one unless you've set up the server to pay attention to it and respond in different formats.

Comment: @Rathinam — If you have a new question, then don't make a comment, [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Make sure you include an [mcve] and quote the error messages, don't just post screenshots … especially screenshots of obfuscated code.

Comment: @Quentin I can't able to post, some reasons i am temporarily block, that's what i am post via reply.

Comment: @Rathinam — If you aren't allowed to ask new questions, then don't try to use comments to bypass the ban!

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax submission already tells that `response` will come as JSON (`type:"POST",`), so you don't need the `var obj=$.parseJSON(response);` line. Also, a better way to debug your code would be using `console.log` instead of `alert`, looking for the results in firebug (extension for Firefox) ou the google chrome console.

In the php code you're testing variables that you've set, you should test `$_POST` variables themselves or use extract on it. You can join these two `if` too, if you want.

It would be like this:

```
require_once '../core/init.php';
extract($_POST);

if(isset($answer_body,$userpost_post_id,$users_user_id) AND
     !empty($answer_body) AND !empty($userpost_post_id) AND !empty($users_user_id)){

     $db=DB::getInstance();
     $result=$db->post_and_fetch("CALL login.post_and_fetch_ans(?,?,?)",array($answer_body,$userpost_post_id,$users_user_id))->result();
          echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSON.parse() method to parse the JSON response into javascript array.

[Click here for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: both should be same.one is plain js and other is jquery ! isn't it ?

Comment: You can use JSON.parse, but that won't help since (a) the data isn't JSON at the point where `$.parseJSON` is called and `$.parseJSON` is just a wrapper around `JSON.parse` anyway (with some stuff to handle JSON in ancient browsers that don't support `JSON.parse`).